# can't connect webhooks bitbucket to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I am configuring Jenkins and webhook like this but my web-hooks are not working.
[image]
here is my webhook configuration
[image]
but I have errors like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LPK8.png)

what i do?

Comment: You get a 403, so check if the credentials are provided and used correctly. Also make sure you are using an app password that has the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the credentials from bitbucket? if so, then you must give it all the permissions and generate your job with those credentials

[image]

In the image I give access to everything to the user for the repository, try to do something similar and validate the url